# Beautifulsoup creating new tag function

Tags: python, html, function, beautifulsoup, tags

I have an existing element and I take text from it and create a new tag with that given text.

```
lesson_name_paragraph = html.new_tag('h1')
lesson_name_paragraph.string = lesson.text
.....            
subject_name_paragraph = html.new_tag('p')
subject_name_paragraph.string = subject_name.text
```

I have ten or more elements that I have to remake for my needs.
Can I create a function that passes arguments and it returns what I'm looking for so I do not have to rewrite so much code?

Comment: Yes. Yes you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass whatever you are repeating into the function. Something like this.

```
def custom_function(tag,item):
    generic_name_paragraph = html.new_tag(tag)
    generic_name_paragraph.string = item.text
    return generic_name_paragraph.string

lesson_name = ('h1',lesson)
subject_name = ('p',subject_name)
```

Comment: You are a legend, thank you. But I modified the return and removed the .string because I needed an element, not a string.